# How to prevent/minimize reflows for this d3 example?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have the following d3 logic for rendering individual objects:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(hugePathDataset)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", (d) => d.properties.cls )
    .attr("id", (d) => d.properties.name )
    .each(... canvas render logic ...)
```

For performance reasons, the `svg` element above is set to `display: none`, the real rendering happens on canvas via `d3`'s projection logic. The svg element is still needed, however, for later updates to canvas (such as changing color of each path individually).

My dataset includes over 60,000 paths and above code takes around 30 seconds to run. Testing it in Chrome's profiler I noticed that 90% of this time is spent in reflow. This made no sense to me since canvas doesn't reflow and the SVG with `display: none` shouldn't reflow the DOM. As I continued looking into it, I realized that the reflow is not triggered by appending elements to invisible SVG, but by setting `class` and `id` attributes on these elements. Sure enough, if I remove lines 4 and 5, the reflow slowdown completely disappears. Setting other attributes (i.e. `data-something`) does not cause a slowdown/reflow.

The problem is that I'm then unable to manipulate these paths individually later, as described above. My questions are:

- Why does adding `class` or `id` to an element with parent set to `display: none` trigger a reflow?
- How can I work around this? How can I get these properties set without the slowdown?

Answer (score 2):

Reading D3 documentation I realized that `selection.append("path")` is equivalent to `selection.append(() => document.createElement("path"))`. Since `document.createElement` does not yet attach the element to the DOM, it should be safe to set properties on it without a reflow. I rewrote the above logic differently and the issue went away:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(hugePathDataset)
    .enter().append((d) => {
        let element = document.createElement("path");
        element.id = d.properties.name;
        element.className = d.properties.cls;
        return element;
    })
    .each(... canvas render logic ...)
```

I still don't understand why class/id change on invisible element causes a reflow, however, but I'm no longer blocked by this.